# How to debug why my Java app crashes?

Tags: java, xml

My app got crashed when I'm using below menu selected code. I use view here to show Snackbar message from outside class. and that why I got error. But it saves data in database

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    View view = new View(this);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_save){
        insertRecord(view);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: you cannot save `view` object into db , what `insertRecord` is doing , post code and error details

Comment: Member of this site for almost 5 years and can't come up with a better title?

Answer (score 0):

After doing many searches, I solved this issue with following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    View view = findViewById(R.id.cl_entry); // id of constraint layout
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_save){
        insertRecord(view);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```